# Alternatives to circular saw for cutting 2x6 wood?

Tags: wood, woodworking, powertools, circular-saw

I need to make straight cuts to several 2x6" pieces of wood and I don't have a circular saw. I was checking several stores and a decent circular saw costs over $70.

What alternatives do I have for clean straight cuts of 2x6 pieces of treated lumber? It doesn't have to be fast, but it has to be clean.

I have a drill and a jigsaw.

Thanks.

Comment: A circular saw is a dangerous piece of equipment. If you borrow one or rent one, be sure to follow all the relevant safety practices. Keep your hands in the right place, use hearing protection, wear safety glasses. But a circular saw is absolutely wonderful at making cross cuts. How many of these 2x6s do you need to cut?

Comment: A circular saw is so loud that it causes confusion to those not used to it. Using hearing protection can prevent serious injury.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can borrow a circular saw, that will probably be best.

That said, you can make a straight cut with the jig saw, but it's going to be slow.  Best results that way would involve clamping boards together so you have a "fence" of sorts that the base of the jig saw will ride against for the whole length of the cut.

Comment: It has been my experience many many many times over that a jig saw cutting a 2x4 or 2x6 will rarely make a cut that stays square with the surface of the wood.

Comment: Keeping square may be an issue, especially when cutting near the edges over long lengths.  I haven't had an issue, but for anything long I'd be using a circular saw or table saw.  As an absolute redneck get-home fix, a sharp blade with the saw oscillating quickly and feeding very slowly might work.  Worst case scenario is a try it and see...

Comment: I ended up buying a circular saw

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Buy a handsaw like this 13-20 dollars. Will cut straight not fast and it will strengthen and tone your arm muscles.

Comment: and a miter box might be useful

Comment: A new saw will be sharp and remain so for some time if treated properly. It will cut in a reasonably short time unless the wood is particularly hard.

Answer (score 0):

Discount companies like "Harbor Freight" sell miter saws and cut saws for around $100.00. Mine, has a 10" blade, and will cut a 2X6 quickly and cleanly. Just be careful when using one; they are quick and unforgiving. If you are not good with motorized tools, do as @Jim Stewart says, but be careful, they will hurt you too.